# How to solve for all z: $z^2+i\sqrt{32}z+6i$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, quadratics

this is my first question and I don't quite understand how do I confront this equation:

$z^2+i\sqrt{32}z-6i=0$

I tried using the quadratic formula but it doesn't seem to give me a correct answer, any help will be much obliged.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Show your steps and (incorrect?) result and we may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if z is a complex number let $z=a+bj$,

$$(a+bj)^2+\sqrt{32}(a+bj)j-6j=0$$
$$\therefore a^2-b^2+2abj+\sqrt{32}aj-\sqrt{32}b-6j=0$$
$$\therefore a^2-b^2-\sqrt{32}b=0, 2abj+\sqrt{32}aj-6j=0$$
These can then be solved simultaneously to find the roots

Comment: I used this but then I got stuck again:
$a=\frac{6}{2b+\sqrt{32}}$

once I put the a into the second equation, I'm getting a 3rd degree polynomial, any help what can I do from there?

Comment: Would just have to use a numerical approximation then for the roots, no easy way to calculate exact roots of a cubic

Answer (score 1):

Note that $z^2+i\sqrt{32}z-6i=(z+i\sqrt{8})^2+(8-6i)$. The problem is essentially$$(z+i\sqrt{8})^2+(8-6i)=0$$

Comment: Looks very useful but I how do I continue from there?

Comment: If you don't have to have the exact answer, you're done. If you want the exact form of answer, just do in the standard way: Let $z=a+bi$. $z^2=-(8-6i)$ and so on.

Comment: unfortunately I try that but then I get a 3rd degree polynomial...
Am I not doing it right?

Comment: $z^2=(a+bi)^2=-(8-6i)$. Then compare coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $z = a + ib$, separate the equation into the real and imaginary parts and equate both parts to $0$.